# input a button value on corresponding textbox that is on focus

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create a touchscreen calculator like where the button value will be placed on the textbox after i set it on a focus by clicking but it appears on all the textboxes.I  tried to use the code

```
if ($(impo).is(":focus")) {
```

but it doesnt work. Please see my snippet
Thanks in advance!

```js
var impo = document.getElementById("imp_text");
var tess = document.getElementById("tess_text");

var FKeyPad = document.Keypad;
var Accumulate = 0;
var FlagNewNum = false;
var PendingOp = "";

document.getElementById('tess').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('tess_text').focus();
}

document.getElementById('imp').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('imp_text').focus();
}

function NumPressed(Num) {

  if (impo) {
    if (FlagNewNum) {
      FKeyPad.ReadOut.value = Num;
      FlagNewNum = false;
    } else {
      if (FKeyPad.ReadOut.value == " ")
        FKeyPad.ReadOut.value = Num;
      else
        FKeyPad.ReadOut.value += Num;
    }
  }


  if (tess) {
    if (FlagNewNum) {
      FKeyPad.readtess.value = Num;
      FlagNewNum = false;
    } else {
      if (FKeyPad.readtess.value == " ")
        FKeyPad.readtess.value = Num;
      else
        FKeyPad.readtess.value += Num;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

      <form name="Keypad" action="">

        <input type="button"  value="Imp" id="imp" /> Importo :
        <input name="ReadOut" id="imp_text" type="Text" value=" "> <br>
        <input type="button" value="Tes" id="tess" /> Card Tess : 
        <input name="readtess" id="tess_text" type="Text" value=" ">
        <br>

        <input type="button" value=" 1" onclick="NumPressed(1)" />
        <input type="button" value=" 2" onclick="NumPressed(2)" />
        <input type="button" value=" 3" onclick="NumPressed(3)" /> <br>

      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (impo)` and `if (tess)` just tests whether the element exists, which they do, so the value gets written to both of them because they both exist. In a desktop environment, you can't do what you're asking - you can give a textbox the focus, but once the user clicks on one of the buttons in order to select that number, the textbox no longer has the focus (because the button has it).

You need a separate way to maintain which textbox is currently selected, something like the snippet below. It will update the currently "selected" element both on the click of the Imp/Tes buttons and whenever either of the textbox gains focus (e.g. by mouse click or touch).

```js
var impo = document.getElementById("imp_text");
var tess = document.getElementById("tess_text");
var current_input = impo;

impo.onfocus = function() {
  current_input = impo;
}
tess.onfocus = function() {
  current_input = tess;
}

document.getElementById('tess').onclick = function() {
  current_input = tess;
  tess.focus();
}

document.getElementById('imp').onclick = function() {
  current_input = impo;
  impo.focus();
}

function NumPressed(Num) {
  current_input.value += Num;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="Keypad" action="">

    <input type="button" value="Imp" id="imp" /> Importo :
    <input name="ReadOut" id="imp_text" type="Text" value=""> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Tes" id="tess" /> Card Tess :
    <input name="readtess" id="tess_text" type="Text" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="1" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" />
    <input type="button" value="2" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" />
    <input type="button" value="3" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" /> <br>
    <input type="button" value="4" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" />
    <input type="button" value="5" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" />
    <input type="button" value="6" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" /> <br>
    <input type="button" value="7" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" />
    <input type="button" value="8" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" />
    <input type="button" value="9" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" /> <br>
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="NumPressed(this.value)" /> <br>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```